# How to Add and Track Tweets, Facebook Likes and Google+ 1 on my website

Tags: social-networking

I would like to have the tweets, Facebook like and G+ buttons on my website. I've seen it on many website but am clueless on how it is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those social buttons can be easily grabbed directly from official websites.

- Tweeter: http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton
- FB: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
- G+: http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

Comment: Thanks. I also found [Google Analytics Social Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSocial.html) useful. @Arti - How do I now close this question? Am being down voted and my reputation is already low as a new user.

Comment: I'm afraid that you cannot close your question on your own.